# which React life cycle method is best appropriate to make API calls on prop change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

We are using React 16.8 version. I'm wondering what is the best-suited life cycle method to perform an API call.

The application I'm using is a typical one. It has a list of items in the left pane and on click of the item, the edit view will be displayed in the right pane. the selected item on the left is being passed as a prop to the right pane component.

Just going over React documentation and I understood that it is not advisable to use ComponentWillRecieveProps anymore and instead we need to use getDerivedStateFromProps and we should simply return the new object that needs to be updated in the state. But, in my use-case, I need to make an API on every prop change and get some additional details on that item.

Could you please advise, what life cycle method is appropriate to do so?

```
I tried updating the state in the right pane component with the props passed from the left pane.

async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.person!== this.state.initialValue) {
        this.setState({
            initialValue: this.props.person,
            editedPerson: Object.assign({}, this.props.person)
        });

        let abc= await this.props.getAbc(this.props.person.dS_KEY);
        this.setState({
            abc
        });
        // Since these are asynchronous and takes random time to finish, I would like them to render when they receive the response from API.
        let def= await this.props.getDef(this.props.person.dS_KEY);
        this.setState({
            def
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb This question has quite detailed context. If that's the answer, please post it in the answer box.

Comment: Are you adverse to using hooks?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Appreciate your response.

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb does componentDidMount called for every state/prop change? (which is what my question was)
What If I have 2 API calls and I called setState for every API change, what will be the order of the lifecycle events.